# PRISM2 commands and silverlight

Tags: silverlight, prism

I have noticed a strange behaviour when using the command functionality in Silverlight:

When the  adding the commands:Click.Command and CommandParameter property, the IsEnabled property stops functioning:

```
<Button Content="Delete" 
    x:Name="Btn_Delete" 
    Margin="0,0,8,0" 
    MinWidth="75" 
    commands:Click.Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" 
    commands:Click.CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDepartment}" 
    IsEnabled="false" />
```

If I remove the commands: attributes the IsEnabled functions correctly. This behaviour is the same if IsEnabled is bound to a value on my view model too.

Is this a bug? Anyone know of any work arounds?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the proper answer too:
http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=50456&ANCHOR&ProjectName=CompositeWPF

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a workaround for now by adding a content control around the button:

```
<ContentControl IsEnabled="false">
<Button Content="Delete" 
    x:Name="Btn_Delete" 
    Margin="0,0,8,0" 
    MinWidth="75" 
    commands:Click.Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" 
    commands:Click.CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDepartment}" 
     />
</ContentControl>
```

Still interested to find any 'proper' solutions though.